# Table view cell deletion animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
       forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Changing the animation type to any of the other options does not make a difference, I seem to get the same animation every time. I've read that this could be due to an `iOS 7` bug, but my deployment target is `iOS 8`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    if ([self.myArray count] >= 1) 
     {
         [self.tableView  beginUpdates];
         [self.tableView  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
         [self.myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
         [self.tableView endUpdates];
      }
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way,

```
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (Object *object in newObjects)
    {
       if (![currentObjects containsObject:object]) {
          int row = [newObjects indexOfObject:object];
          NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
          [indexPathsToDelete addObject:indexPath];
       }
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];
```